# Show icon on the header of p:panel

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using the component [`<p:panel>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/panel/panel.xhtml)

If we take the Advanced Panel as an example, is there any way that makes me able to add an icon at the left of the text "About Barca"?

Answer (score 4):

You can extend the header using `<f:facet name="header">`

```
<f:facet name="header">
  <h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <span class="ui-icon" />
    <h:outputText value="About Barca" />
  </h:panelGrid>
</f:facet>
```

You can use a `span` element plus CSS customization or the `p:graphicImage` component.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you can add an icon to a panel component:

```
<p:panel header="the header text you want">
    <f:facet name="actions">
        <p:commandLink
            styleClass="ui-panel-titlebar-icon ui-corner-all ui-state-default">
            <h:outputText styleClass="ui-icon ui-icon-help" />
        </p:commandLink>
    </f:facet>
</p:panel>
```